# Issue starting cmd.exe twice in a row

Tags: java, batch-file, process, runtime.exec

I am trying to automate some processes that were build in ancient times, for the sake of avoiding repetitive actions. It is required that the processes are started with one batch and stopped with another (this can not be changed btw).

So i made a commandline tool to do this (and many other repetitive stuff) and I have modelled a command that starts the 'startbatch' and a command that start the 'stopbatch'. Both commands work fine separatly (as I tested them separatly) but there seems to be a problem when i want execute them one after another (in the correct order ofcourse). I get the following error in new cmd.exe window:

*The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.*

the code that i am using to start the batches looks like this:

```
public void startBatchInDev(String company){
    String startBatchFolder = locations.getLocationFor("startbatch");

    try{
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec("cmd.exe /C cd \"" + startBatchFolder + "\" & start cmd.exe /k \"" + BATCHSTART + company.toLowerCase()+ "-dev"  + BATCH_SUFFIX + "\"");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopBatchInDev(String company){
    String startBatchFolder = locations.getLocationFor("startbatch");

    try{
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec("cmd.exe /C cd \"" + startBatchFolder + "\" & start cmd.exe /k \"" + BATCHSTOP + company.toLowerCase()+ "-dev"  + BATCH_SUFFIX + "\"");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The names of the batchfiles are concatenated, but they are OK once the application is running.

The error message is quite clear, some file is locked and I can't access it because of it. Some googling confirms my suspicion, but I can't seem to find a solution for this. The hits in google are all about obvious uses of files, like an obvious shared resource. But in my case, i am not working on the same batch file. The stop and start batch are two different files. So I am actually starting to think that it might be the cmd.exe file that is being locked by windows...

So this question is actually two questions: 
- what is the exact cause of the described problem?
- how do i programmatically fix this (if possible)?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try a tool like `http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html` to investigate what is going on.

Comment: @Gene thank you. I ll try it right away. I ll update the status when I know more.

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: Have you looked at the content of your BATCHSTART and BATCHSTOP scripts? I suspect they are both trying to write to the same file. Windows is not locking cmd.exe.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for the advice. I had a quick look yesterday already. I'll make work of your other remarks about the ProcessBuilder and the String array as well.

Comment: @dbenham Thanks as well. Your remark makes sense (that much even, that i actually feel stupid I didnt check it myself). In the batch scripts, there is no reference of writing to a file. However, the scripts start and stop procedures in a 4GL language. They might both be trying to write to the same logfile...

Comment: So i started digging deeper into the entire process starting and runtime environment scene. First I tried with a tool trying to see if any files were opened that seems like they should not be open. But no clue there. Then i started changing my code and just try as much as possible. I implemented most of pitfall solutions (those that seemed related). I also tried the ProcessBuilder, which gave results but unwanted results. If somebody accidently find the answer, I am interested. But I think I will conclude with just excluding the entire batch thing from my automation program.

Answer (score 1):

So, basically, bat is not so great :-(
I was able to repro this from java, but I also found that this script:

```
@echo off
echo STOP
echo STOP >> E:\tmp\java\logfile.txt
C:\cygwin\bin\sleep.exe 1
echo STOP1 >> E:\tmp\java\logfile.txt
C:\cygwin\bin\sleep.exe 1
echo STOP2 >> E:\tmp\java\logfile.txt
```

When run twice like this:

```
start test.bat && start test.bat
```

Will fail with one or more messages like:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

The reason is that " >> " redirection opens the file for Read/Write access but only FILE_SHARE_READ sharing. If two different programs attempt to open the file this way, one of them fails.

So, you cannot have two different batch files running at the same time and logging to the same file